# How to get MsgBox only if first cell in the active column has some value?

Tags: vba, excel

Im trying to exit if first cell in the active column is not "abc"

```
If Not Cells(1, ActiveCell.Column).Value = "abc" Then Exit Sub
MsgBox ("323")
```

Whatever is the first cell in the active column - MsgBox doesn't appear.

Comment: I would avoid using `activecell` to start with.

Comment: Why to avoid activecell ? (How to determine in another way) the first cell in the "active column" ?

Comment: Your code works for me (Excel 2010). Can you show more of the code around your sample? What happens when you debug? Can you see if `Cells(1, ActiveCell.Column).Value = "abc"` returns `True` or `False`?

Comment: @OlleSjögren, I found my mistake - an extra blank space in the first cell. Please, excuse me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
If Cells(1, ActiveCell.Column).Value <> "abc" Then Exit Sub
MsgBox ("323")
```

Comment: 000 it works. Why my code doesn't work ? AnyWay, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You're exiting the sub before the msgbox is called.  Call the msgbox then exit the sub.

Comment: But, I don't want to exit sub if the first cell has value "abc". My column has this value in its first cell.

Comment: I'm confused.  If you don't want to exit the sub, then remove "exit sub".  What am I missing?

Comment: @ dwstein, if first cell is "abc" - then go to msgbox. If first cell is not "abc" - go to exit